# using multiple JUnit results file on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

On my Jenkins pipleline I run unit tests on both: debug and release configurations. Each test configuration generates separate JUnit XML results file. Test names on both: debug and release configuration are same. Currently I use the following `junit` command in order to show test results:

`junit allowEmptyResults: true, healthScaleFactor: 0.0, keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'Test-Dir/Artifacts/test_xml_reports_*/*.xml'`

The problem is that on Jenkins UI both: debug and release tests results are shown together and it is not possible to know which test (from debug or release configuration) is failed.
Is it possible to show debug and release tests results separately? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I am hitting the same problem.

Comment: I modified XML format and included build variant name (debug/release) as a package name to prevent this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks no solution for my question.
As a workaround I changed JUnit XML report format and included build variant name (debug/release) as a package name.

Answer (score 2):

We run the same integration tests against two different configurations with different DB types.  We use maven and the failsafe plugin, so I take advantage of the `-Dsurefire.reportNameSuffix` so I can see the difference between the two runs.

The following is an example block of our `Jenkinsfile`:

```
    stage('Integration test MySql') {
        steps {
            timeout(75) {
                sh("mvn -e verify -DskipUnitTests=true -DtestConfigResource=conf/mysql-local.yaml " +
                    "-DintegrationForkCount=1 -DdbInitMode=migrations -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false " +
                    "-Dsurefire.reportNameSuffix=MYSQL")
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                junit '**/failsafe-reports/*MYSQL.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

In the report, the integration tests run against mysql then show up with MYSQL appended to their name.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I want to make a distinction between unit tests and integration tests in the results.
This is how Jenkins pipeline looks like
junit testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml, **/target/failsafe-reports/*.xml'

But Jenkins just merges the two reports and i can't make a difference between unit and integration test?